# How to add ASP.NET web project as a reference in WIX setup project?

Tags: .net, asp.net, wix

I want to create a sample installer of web application (ASP.NET) using WIX. 
I created a sample asp.net web project, then added a WIX setup project in the solution. 
While reading tutorials, I was told to add a reference for my sample web app in the WIX setup project. But when I right-clicked and select add references in the WIX setup project, I can't find any projects in the projects tab? Please help.

Comment: What template have you used to create your ASP.NET app?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure understanding your question but 
- if you try to create a wix project and deploy an asp.net  web application you must add the reference to WixIIsExtension, WixUIExtension, WixUtilsExtension
 you can find it in :
C: \ Program Files\ Windows Installer XML v3.5 \ bin

- if you want to add your web application to an existing IIS web site , i [think this link is good](http://www.cmcrossroads.com/cm-basics/12907-installing-a-web-application-to-an-existing-iis-website-using-wix3)

hope it helps you